# Pivot a pandas dataframe wherein the values of dataframe become indexes, retaining the columns and new df value are the list of original index

Tags: python, pandas

So given a dataframe of the format. How to get the following result?
Without requiring to create a one hot encoding to create a 3D numpy array and later dot product.

```
my_idx         c1   c2  c3          
idx1          v11   v12 v13
idx2          v12   v11 v11
idx3          v13   v11 v12
```

Expected result:

```
new_idx      c1         c2            c3        
v11        [idx1]   [idx2, idx3]    [idx2]
v12        [idx2]   [idx1]          [idx3]
v13        [idx3]   []              [idx1]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `my_idx` as the index (if it is not already),
2. Get the dataframe into the *long* form with `DataFrame.stack`,
3. Group by the two *pivot* columns and aggregate the values into lists,
4. Unstack the dataframe to the wide form.

You could do the following:

```py
df.set_index('my_idx').stack().reset_index().groupby([0, 'level_1']).my_idx.apply(list).unstack()
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this may not be required
```

this results in the following output for me.

```
level_1      c1            c2      c3
0
v11      [idx1]  [idx2, idx3]  [idx2]
v12      [idx2]        [idx1]  [idx3]
v13      [idx3]           NaN  [idx1]
```

Comment: You're a genius; I couldn't understand this question or its expected output at all. Congrats and +1